# Mocking a method inside a Scala class using Mockito

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, jvm

I am working with the following Scala class:

```
class names(lastName: String) {

  def getFullName(lastName: String): String = get_private_name + lastName

  def getPrivateName: String = "amit"

}
```

I need to test the getFullName method and I want to mock the getPrivateName function inside this class.

In Python, I would typically perform this task as follows:

```
def test_getPrivateName() {
   with mock.path(names.getPrivateName) as mocked_getPrivateName {
      names_cls = names("my_last_name")
      mocked_getPrivateName.return_value = "ido"
      self.assertEqual("ido my_last_name", names_cls.getFullName())
   }
}
```

I'm trying to replicate this same behavior in Scala with Mockito but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that this is somehow a design smell if you have to do that. Most of the time, you shouldn't need to mock private methods. If this happens, either your unit of test is too small, or your class responsibility is too large.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking methods of a class you are testing, while possible (look up "Mockito spy" if you still want to use it), is not a good idea, and code smell, as pointed out in the comments.

There is usually a better way. Like, in this case, just make `privateName` a variable set in constructor, there is no need to mock it at all:

```
class Names(lastName: String, val privateName: String = "amit") { 
   def fullName = privateName + lastName
}

def test_stuff() = {
    val testMe = new Names("foo", "bar") 
    testMe.fullName mustBe "foobar"
}
```